# How to return an incremented variable to next recursion call on the recursion stack?

Tags: python, recursion

So I am answering a question where we are given a flight of stairs that we need to climb and some `target height`. We are told the `maximum number of steps` we can take with each step. And we are asked to return the number of ways we can reach this target height, using `recursion`.

let's say that `target height is 3`, and the `max steps is 2`.
Then the solution would be 3, since we can take the following steps `#1,1,1` `#1,2` and `#2,1` to reach the target height.

Here is my code below:

```
def staircaseTraversal(height, maxSteps):
    numberOfWays = 0
    staircaseTraversalHelper(height, maxSteps, 0, 0)
    if numberOfWays:
        return numberOfWays
    return -1


def staircaseTraversalHelper(height, maxSteps, currentHeight, numberOfWays):
    for step in range(1, maxSteps+1):
        newHeight = currentHeight + step
        if newHeight == height:
            return numberOfWays + 1
        elif newHeight < height:
            staircaseTraversalHelper(height, maxSteps, newHeight, numberOfWays)
```

My question is regarding updating the numberOfWays when we hit such a point where the current step we are on (newHeight) is equal to the target height, and we increment the numberOfWays by 1, I am then struggling to return this `numberOfWays` to the next recursion call on the recursion stack!

At the moment I am doing return `numberOfWays + 1` - but I don't think this is correct. I also tried `incrementing numberOfWays by 1`, then simply breaking out of the `for loop`, then `returning nothing` to get to the next recursion call in the recursion stack, but this doesn't seem to work either.

Also, it would be great if I could get feedback on the set up of my overall recursive solution, as I am quite new to the ideas, albeit I do understand it quite comprehensively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like below.
Here, `height` argument means the "remaining height", so I subtract steps for the recursive calls.
Note that you may also use `sum` to reduce the number of lines.

```py
def staircaseTraversal(height, maxSteps):
    if height == 0:
        return 1
    if height < 0:
        return 0

    out = 0
    for step in range(1, min(height, maxSteps) + 1):
        out += staircaseTraversal(height - step, maxSteps)
    return out

staircaseTraversal(3, 2)
# 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution to your answer, instead of adding a new argument "currentHeight", you can do it like this

```
def staircaseTraversal(height, maxSteps):
    numbersOfWays = 0
    for step in range(1, maxSteps+1):
        if height == step:
            numbersOfWays +=1
            break
        elif height < step:
            break
        else:
            numbersOfWays += staircaseTraversal(height -step, maxSteps)
    return numbersOfWays
print(staircaseTraversal(3,2))
```